# Overide Variable in Child Theme

Tags: php, functions, child-theme, variables

I am trying to change the `h1` tag in the head of my child theme from "Blog" to "Resources". The parent theme enqueues files with `require_once` and `get_template_directory` so it's very difficult to overwrite file through child theming. If anyone has a solution to that it would be great, but if not I thought I would just attempt to modify the variable in my functions file instead.

The parent theme uses this code basically.

```
function print_page_title() {
    global $post;
    $page_title = get_the_title($page_id);
    if(is_home()) {
        $page_title = esc_html__('Blog','crexis');
    } ?>

    <h1><?php echo esc_textarea($page_title); ?></h1><?php
}
```

(For testing purposes) if I modify it this way it works:

```
function print_page_title() {
    global $post;
    $page_title = get_the_title($page_id);
    if(is_home()) {
        $page_title = esc_html__('Blog','crexis');
    }

    if ( 'Blog' == $page_title ) {
        $page_title = 'Resources' ;
    } ?>
    <h1><?php echo esc_textarea($page_title); ?></h1><?php
}
```

But this (and other variations I've tried) doesn't work if I put the following in my child's functions.php:

```
function resources_header() {
    global $page_title;
    if ( 'Blog' == $page_title ) {
        $page_title = 'Resources' ;
    }
}
add_action( 'print_page_title', 'resources_header' );
```

I've also tried `add_filter` instead of `add_action` OR `after_setup_theme` instead of `print_page_title`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `print_page_title` used in parent theme and how? Is it hooked to any action?

Comment: It's just `if(!function_exists('print_page_title')) { function print_page_title() {...}`. Found in /framework/functions/header-functions.php. I can't find another reference to it anywhere.

Comment: Actually, that's not correct, I just fond it in the header.php file: `if(!is_front_page() && ( theme_option('header_title') != 0 || theme_option('header_title') == '') && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'page_header', true) != 'no-header' && !is_page_template('template-onepager.php') || is_search() && theme_option('header_title') != 0) {  
  print_page_title();
 }`

Answer (score 1):

To override the variable directly add the fucntion `print_page_title` in child theme `functions.php` this should work as the parent theme uses `if(!function_exists('print_page_title'))` condition to check for the function, since child theme's `function.php` is loaded first this is used instead of parent theme.

Place the following code in your child-theme's `functions.php`

```
function print_page_title() {
    global $post;
    $page_title = get_the_title($page_id);
    if(is_home()) {
        $page_title = esc_html__('Blog','crexis');
    }

    if ( 'Blog' == $page_title ) {
        $page_title = 'Resources' ;
    } ?>
    <h1><?php echo esc_textarea($page_title); ?></h1><?php
}
```

---

```
add_action( 'print_page_title', 'resources_header' );
```

The above doesn't work because there is no action hook `print_page_title`. It works if the code in your parent theme is like:

```
if(!is_front_page() && ( theme_option('header_title') != 0 '' ....//conditions)  {
    do_action('print_page_title');
}
```

---

```
add_filter( 'print_page_title', 'resources_header' );
```

will work if the funcion in parent theme function is like:

```
function print_page_title() {
    global $post;
    $page_title = get_the_title($page_id);
    if(is_home()) {
        $page_title = esc_html__('Blog','crexis');
    } 

    $page_title = apply_filters('print_page_title',$page_title);

    ?>

    <h1><?php echo esc_textarea($page_title); ?></h1><?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, the only problem is it's a HUGE function. I cut a lot out for simplicity's sake. I think other things hook into it from there.